# Is there a formal definition of character difference across a string and if so how is it calculated?

Tags: string, algorithm, passwords, character

#### Overview

I'm looking to analyse the difference between two characters as part of a password strength checking process.

I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve and why and would like to know if what I'm looking to do is formally defined and whether there are any recommended algorithms for achieving this.

#### What I'm looking to do

Across a whole string, I'm looking to compare the current character with the previous character and determine how different they are.

As this relates to password strength checking, the difference between one character and it's predecessor in a string might be defined as being how predictable character N is from knowing character N - 1. There might be a formal definition for this of which I'm not aware.

#### Example

A password of `abc123` could be arguably less secure than `azu590`. Both contain three letters followed by three numbers, however in the case of the former the sequence is more predictable.

I'm assuming that a password guesser might try some obvious sequences such that `abc123` would be tried much before `azu590`.

Considering the decimal ASCII values for the characters in these strings, and given that `b` is 1 different from `a` and `c` is 1 different again from `b`, we could derive a simplistic difference calculation.

Ignoring cases where two consecutive characters are not in the same character class, we could say that `abc123` has an overall character to character difference of 4 whereas `azu590` has a similar difference of 25 + 5 + 4 + 9 = 43.

#### Does this exist?

This notion of character to character difference across a string might be defined, similar to the Levenshtein distance between two strings. I don't know if this concept is defined or what it might be called. Is it defined and if so what is it called?

My example approach to calculating the character to character difference across a string is a simple and obvious approach. It may be flawed, it may be ineffective. Are there any known algorithms for calculating this character to character difference effectively?

Comment: Apart from the obvious alphabetical order, you also need to consider the keyboard order. `azerty` or `qwerty` might not be very correlated from an alphabetical point of view, yet they are just so easy to type. You would also have to consider existing words (dictionary attacks), etc... it seems a very difficult task you're set yourself too.

Comment: @Matthieu M: Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, I realise that considering keyboard sequences are important. The example I gave is simply that - just a rough example - and there are many things to consider. The question relates to merely one of many rules that a password strength checker uses and dictionary words are not relevant to this rule. I have other rules covering certain properties of passwords such that dictionary words and proper nouns are covered without needing a dictionary or list of proper nouns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [Markov Chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) model for passwords. A Markov Chain has a number of states and a probability of transitioning between the states. In your case the states are the characters in the allowed character set and the probability of a transition is proportional to the frequency that those two letters appear consecutively. You can construct the Markov Chain by looking at the frequency of the transitions in an existing text, for example a freely available word list or password database.

It is also possible to use variations on this technique (*Markov chain of order m*) where you for example consider the previous two characters instead of just one.

Once you have created the model you can use the probability of generating the password from the model as a measure of its strength. This is the product of the probabilities of each state transition.

Answer (score 1):

For general signals/time-series data, this is known as [Autocorrelation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)
You could try adapting the [Durbin–Watson statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic) and test for positive auto-correlation between the characters. A naïve way may be to use the unicode code-points of each character, but I'm sure that will not be good enough.